# for文を用いたDate.Nowの時間処理

Tags: c#

プログラム初学者です。
Visual Studio 2019を用いてC#で機械学習のためのデータを取るプログラムを作っています。

#### やりたいこと

for文を回しiの値によってファイル名を変える。
一秒ごとに各種パラーメーターをtxtに出力する。

#### 問題点

現状データが取得出来てはいるが、データが一秒ごとに取得できず、秒数がとびとびになっている。
値を一秒ごとに取得する方法をご教授ください。

#### 試したこと

for文の中身を60以外に変更しても一秒に一回データを取ることができなかった。

#### 現状のコード

```csharp
    string fileName;
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        if (NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValueStatus(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_ATTENTION) != 0)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                fileName = fileNameFolder + "data0.txt";
            }
            else if (i <= 21)
            {
                fileName = fileNameFolder + "data1to21.txt";
            }
            else if (i == 22)
            {
                SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                fileName = fileNameFolder + "data22.txt";
            }
            else if (i <= 52)
            {
                fileName = fileNameFolder + "data23to43.txt";
            }
            else if (i == 44)
            {
                SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                fileName = fileNameFolder + "data44.txt";
            }
            else
            {
                fileName = fileNameFolder + "data45to60.txt";
            }

            using (StreamWriter filewrite000 = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
            {
                attention = NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_ATTENTION);
                meditation = NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_MEDITATION);
                delta = NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_DELTA);
                theta = NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_THETA);
                lowalpha = NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_ALPHA1);
                highalpha = NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_ALPHA2);
                lowbeta = NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_BETA1);
                highbeta = NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_BETA2);
                lowgamma = NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_GAMMA1);
                highgamma = NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_GAMMA2);
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

                filewrite000.Write(attention + ", " + meditation + ", " + delta + ", " + theta + ", " + lowalpha + ", " + highalpha + ", " + lowbeta + ", " + highbeta + ", " + lowgamma + ", " + highgamma + ", " + dt.ToString() + ", " + state+"\n");
                Console.WriteLine(" ATTENTION: MEDITATION: STATE: DELTA: THETA: LOWALPHA: HIGHALPHA: LOWBETA: HIGHBETA: LOWGAMMA: HIGHGAMMA: " + attention, +meditation, +state, +delta, +theta, +lowalpha, +highalpha, +lowbeta, +highbeta, +lowgamma, +highgamma, dt.ToString());
            }
        }

        if (NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValueStatus(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_RAW) != 0)
        {
            if (NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValueStatus(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.MWM15_DATA_FILTER_TYPE) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Find Filter Type: " + NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.MWM15_DATA_FILTER_TYPE) + " index: " + packetsRead);
                //break;//実装//
            }

            /* Get and print out the updated raw value */
            NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValue(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_RAW);

            packetsRead++;
            if (packetsRead == 800 || packetsRead == 1600) // call twice interval than 1s (512)
            {
                errCode = NativeThinkgear.MWM15_getFilterType(connectionID);
                Console.WriteLine(" MWM15_getFilterType called: " + errCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 提示されたソースコードのどの部分で1秒の間隔を計っている(or決定している)のでしょう？ それと`for`で`0`～`59`をループするのと何が関係しているのでしょう？ あるいはデータを取得するタイミング/間隔とファイルに1秒毎に出力するのは別々の時間の尺度で動いている処理ですか？ その辺の情報を追記してください。ちなみにソースコードに示された名前で検索するとこの辺のものと思われますが、そうしたものの何を使ってどうしようとしているかといった情報もあると助けになるかもしれません。[NeuroSky](https://www.neurosky.jp/), [Documentation](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=neurosky_101), [Using the ThinkGear Native Library in Unity](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=app_notes:using_thinkgear_with_unity.pdf)

Comment: TG_GetValueStatus(connectionId, TG_DATA_ATTENTION) != 0
でattentionの値が更新されたら、データを取得となっています。
なので１秒間に１回更新してるはずです。
http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=app_notes:torque:thinkgear_testapp.cpp.pdf

Comment: 一応ここ [eSense(tm) Meters](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=esenses_tm) に`By default, output of this Data Value is enabled. It is typically output once a second.`とあるので1秒毎という仕様にはなっていそうです。ただし`typically`なので必ずしも正確ではなさそうですが。例えばファイル名変更/ビープ鳴動/データ読み出し/ファイル出力といった処理は全部削ぎ落として、`TG_GetValueStatus(...) != 0`でattentionの値が更新されたタイミングで、`DateTime.Now`の(ミリ秒まで含んだ)値を`Console.WriteLine()`するだけの確認プログラムを作って、本当に1秒毎に通知されているか試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ちなみに関連する名前の別の情報は、また別の周期で発生していそうで`raw EEG wave samples`(ソースの`TG_DATA_RAW`?)はループ内の別の部分で処理しているようですが、そうした別々のデータの処理を1つの`for`ループにまとめて入れていることが何か影響しているかもしれませんね。[What are the different EEG Band Frequencies?](http://support.neurosky.com/kb/science/eeg-band-frequencies), [ThinkGear Data Types](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=mindset_data_types)

Comment: https://github.com/amastaneh/MindWaveReader/raw/master/NeuroSky%20Library/20170326-Windows-Developer-Tools-3.2.zip にサンプルプログラムが入っているので参考にしてみてはどうでしょうか。例えば、`Windows Developer Tools 3.2/Stream SDK for PC/Sample Project/x64/thinkgear_testapp/thinkgear_testapp/thinkgear_testapp.c` はヘッドセットからの脳波データを 5 秒間読み込んで stdout にそのデータを出力しています(C# ではなく C ですが)。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/365734

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます

Comment: @WebSurfer さん、マルチポストのご指摘ありがとうごうざいます！　一方、スタック・オーバーフローではマルチポストを禁止している訳ではありません。コメントで単にマルチポストであることだけを指摘するのだと、特にサイト初心者の方は何をすれば良いのかが分かりません。質問者が投稿を改善するのに役立つ建設的な指摘となるように書いていただけますと幸いです。以前こちらでそのような議論をいたしました: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3087/19110

Comment: 本来は質問者がマルチポスト先の url を書いておくべきと思いますが、それをしてないので自分が書いておきました。質問欄に追記する、無視する、ご自由に。

Comment: 結局、タイマークラスは試されたのでしょうか？使えない理由があるなら、回答にコメントお願いします。

Comment: 立て込んでいてタイマークラスは試せておりません。また、いまタイマークラスをいまあるコードに追記する方法を勉強中ですので今しばらくお待ちください。

Comment: 返信遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。タイマークラスを試したところ、一秒ごとにデータを取得し、フォルダーを仕分けることが出来ました。
有難うございました。

Comment: 問題が解決したのであれば、質問をクローズしてください。

Answer (score 3):

普通は、.NETの定周期処理はタイマークラスを使います。
タイマークラスも何種類かありますが、[System.Timers.Timer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0)が無難だと思います。
[タイマにより一定時間間隔で処理を行うには？（サーバベースタイマ編）](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/0511/11/news119.html)

提示されているソースで使用されているクラス、メソッドがどういったものか不明で、何の説明も記載されていない為、何をやってるのかさっぱり判りませんが、とびとびになっているということは、処理に1秒より多く掛かってるんじゃないですか？
[Stopwatchクラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0)で、各処理に掛かっている時間を計測してみてください。